# Firestore Db queries with link

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a Firestore DB REST API Query.

Problem is, I'm using a low code tool which insists that GET requests have no bodies and POST requests are difficult to deal with.

So, I fugured, i can just use Firestore REST API queries using link.

Like this: [https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{collection_id}?orderBy={field_name}&pageSize=1&descending=true](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7Bproject_id%7D/databases/%7Bdatabase_id%7D/documents/%7Bcollection_id%7D?orderBy=%7Bfield_name%7D&pageSize=1&descending=true)

What's the equivalent of this to run Query? ChatGPT gives me wrong answers lol.

I wanna run a query that returns when the field 'category' matches 'electronics'

Comment: Where are you going to display the results, on the user's device?

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: What do you mean by "What's the equivalent of this to run Query?"?

Comment: @AlexMamo is there a way to run firestore queris without using request body, but only using a URL endpoint